In Codefinity Python course, when a task is submitted by clicking Submit Task, what do the red X's preceding the statements mean?
I'm taking the Codefinity beginner's Python course, where a "Task" is coding by the user, following the instructions given. When I've finished the code and click Run Code, errors are explained, and the code can be corrected. Then, when Submit Task is clicked, several lines appear, some of which may be preceded red X's. What do those X's mean?
